# spark writing data into share table of mysql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a periodic spark-scala task which to transfer data from Hive to MySQL.

The structure of table can be simply regarded as:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
```

Then because of the hive table is too large, so i have to share MySQL tables.

So Here is my current solution:

1. Preparing MySQL tables:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_test_db |
+-------------------+
| shared_0          |
| shared_1          |
| shared_2          |
| shared_3          |
| shared_4          |
| shared_5          |
+-------------------+
```

2. Load data from Hive and do some transform operations then generate the dataframe I want

```
val data = List((0, "a"), (11, "b"), (22, "c"), (33, "d"), (44, "e"))
val total = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
  .toDF("id", "name")
  .withColumn("hashCode", hash($"id")%5)
```

3. Save data into MySQL table according to `hashCode` column

```
(0 to 5).foreach(hashCode => {
  val df = total.where($"hashCode" === hashCode).select("id", "name")
  df.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"shared_$hashCode", connectionProperties)
})
```

And this works fine, but i am a newbie of spark, so i'd like to know is there better way to implement what i want??

---

UPDATE:

Here is my full code:

```
val jdbcHostname = "localhost"
val jdbcPort = 3306
val jdbcDatabase = "test_db"
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}"
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", "user")
connectionProperties.put("password", "password")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val data = List((0, "a"), (11, "b"), (22, "c"), (33, "d"), (44, "e"))
val total = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
  .toDF("id", "name")
  .withColumn("hashCode", hash($"id")%5)

(0 to 5).foreach(hashCode => {
  val df = total.where($"hashCode" === hashCode).select("id", "name")
  df.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"shared_$hashCode", connectionProperties)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I do not see serialization error aspects, what you are simply doing is 5 sequential DF calls via a loop, but the foreach is not tied to underlying RDDs.

The comments I can make is that a .cache or .persist may be an improvement. Additionally repartition by column on total df would allow faster access.

Comment: What is serialization error?? Could you give an example??

Comment: no you do not have serialization error, all good. just a comment.

Comment: Instead of using jdbc connector, that would be better when using pure mysql connector. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html